# How to extract variable from script tag in html blob

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

I am trying to figure out how to extract a variable from a giant string of html. A simplified example is below:

**Update** Here is a screen shot of trying to use the common approach called out below. Doing something as simple as `test['foo']` doesn't work. This is a string returned from a server and is never loaded into the actual document or window. It's just an html object that's kept in memory.

[image]

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/hvpvg3o4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="test"> <!-- div is just for jsfiddle -->
  <script>
    var test = { // <-- I WANT YOU!
      foo: 'bar'
    };

    var somethingIDontWant = 1;
    var iDontCareAboutYouEither = {
        blag: 1 + 1
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var testTag = document.getElementById('test');
var scriptTag = testTag.getElementsByTagName('script');
// var testObj = ?;
```

I was hoping that I could just get the text from the script tag and either run eval or some JSON.parse, but since there's other stuff within the script tag, I can't

Is there some way to extract a variable from a script tag or some fancy regex to do so?

Comment: Can you explain a bit why do you want to do something like that? Where is your javascript or html string coming from?

Comment: eval(scriptTag.innerHTML);
console.log(test.foo);

Comment: I am trying to extract a URL from a response that's got a bunch of HTML. Right now, I don't have the option on getting on the server and fixing that process, so I'm basically stuck with a script tag and inline javascript. It's a bandaid fix but trying to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
console.log(test['foo'])
console.log(somethingIDontWant)
console.log(iDontCareAboutYouEither['blag'])
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <script>
    var test = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };

    var somethingIDontWant = 1;
    var iDontCareAboutYouEither = {
      blag: 1 + 1
    };
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question. The variable that I'm after isn't attached to the window/document. It's in memory

Comment: After you load test div from memory try to use $(document) might help

Answer (score 0):

If the object that is desired is declared in the *global* scope. The desired object will be accessible anytime a **script** tag is declared.

**Example:**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
    var test = {
      foo: 'bar'
    };

    var somethingIDontWant = 1;
    var iDontCareAboutYouEither = {
        blag: 1 + 1
    };
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV>UGLY HTML</DIV>
<SCRIPT>
//INSERT CUSTOM SCRIPT FOR ACCESSING DESIRED OBJECT//
console.log(test)
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The console can *still* access var test..even in later defined script in the body...

**Output:**
{foo: 'bar'}